# Function on Matrix and Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to perform a matrix-valued function on a matrix $a$ and a vector $b$ defined by:

$$c_{ij} = \sum_k a_{ik} b_{j}$$

This is equivalent (I think) to multiplying $a$ by another matrix (of appropriate size) where each column of the matrix is the (column) vector $b$.

I'm looking to implement this function using a standard linear algebra package in an efficient manner. Is there a way to re-write this function in terms of standard linear algebra functions (ie., matrix multiplications), without having to create a new (potentially large) matrix filled with the $b$ vector?

I understand this is not the place to ask coding/implementation questions, but I think the scope of my question is purely math-based - the implementation specifics were only included to motivate the question.

Comment: There is almost no computation: in $c_{ij} =( \sum_k a_{ik}) b_{j}$ (notice the parenthesis I have placed), the summation $ \sum_k a_{ik} $ amounts to sum all the lines of the matrix A, say, a column vector, $(L_1,L_2... L_N)^T$, then built by a standard "double for loop" the array of all $c_{ij}=L_i b_j$. No need for a special linear algebra package.

Comment: The advantage of using matrix operations over a `for` loop is that in many interpreted languages (ie. Python), a `for` loop would be rather slow, while the linear algebra package is implemented in a faster and more efficient manner (and possibly even GPU accelerated, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us note that if we have two column vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ then the matrix $T_{ij} = u_i v_j$ can be viewed as the so called [dyadic product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_vectors#Operations) and is obtained by

$\mathbf T = \mathbf u \otimes \mathbf v = \mathbf u \mathbf v^T$ (the order matters)

I am bringing this up because you may view

$\sum_k a_{ik} b_j = \left (\sum_k a_{ik} \right ) b_j$

as the dyadic product between a column vector $\sum_k a_{ik}$ (with i:as the index) and the column vector $b_j$.

Now the entries in the column vector $x_i =\sum_k a_{ik}$ are actually the sums of of the rows of the matrix $\mathbf A$. This summing of rows can be obtained by multiplying by a column vector with all ones from the right.

$\mathbf x = \mathbf A (1,1,...,1)^T$

The fact that $x_i = \sum_{k}a_{ik}$ is straightforward to check.
Plugging it into the dyadic product we get

$\boxed{\mathbf C = \mathbf x \mathbf b^T = \mathbf A (1,1,...,1)^T \mathbf b^T}$

MATLAB and most languages have short functions for generating row/column vectors with all 1:es.

Comment: This is beautiful! Exactly what I was looking for.